# Expanded lookup in Tasks for a custom object in Visualforce

Tags: salesforce, visualforce

I'm very new at this, I would appreciate some help. I am trying to create an expanded lookup field for the Activities (Tasks) page since in Visualforce. I want it to lookup a custom object which I called telemarketers.

Here's what I have so far and I can't seem to make it work!

```
<apex:page standardController="Task">
  <apex:form >
    <apex:inputField value="{!task.telemarketer.name_c}"/>
  </apex:form>
</apex:page>
```

I've tried changing the {!task.telemarketer.name_c} for other things but I keep getting errors like 
" Invalid field telemarketer for SObject Task"
"Could not resolve field 'telemarketername_c' from  value binding '{!task.telemarketername_c}' in page Sample1 "
"Could not resolve field 'telemarketername' from  value binding '{!task.telemarketername}' in page Sample1 "

HELP PLEASE!! im going crazy

Answer (score 0):

Following are my Observations

1) Not sure if you are using Id on the apex page 
Url should be like - https://c.ap1.visual.force.com/apex/test?id=00T90000010uTKC
Id is required since you are trying to input field of a particular record.

2) Regarding field names, please select the api name of the field in the visualforce page.

Eg. code here

```
<apex:page standardController="Task">
  <apex:form >
    <apex:pageBlock title="My Content" mode="edit"> 
      <apex:pageBlockSection title="My Content Section" columns="2">
         <apex:inputfield value="{!task.status}"/>
         <apex:inputfield value="{!task.whoid}"/>
      </apex:pageBlockSection>
    </apex:pageBlock>
  </apex:form>
</apex:page>
```

Answer (score 0):

To use the standard Salesforce lookup dialog, next Visualforce markup should work (assuming you have created a custom field for Task sObject with API name "Telemarketer__c"):

```
<apex:page standardController="Task">
<apex:form >
<apex:pageBlock title="Task Details" mode="edit"> 
  <apex:pageBlockSection title="Task Telemarketer Lookup Field" columns="1">
    <apex:inputfield value="{!task.Telemarketer__c}"/>
  </apex:pageBlockSection>
</apex:pageBlock>
```

Also please note that field expressions expect field names with double underscores ("__c") in the API name:

```
Task.Telemarketer__c // this is correct
Task.Telemarketer_c  // unknown field "Telemarketer_c" for object Task
```